# How to Search Datagridview (Stored Procedure Data) using Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Windows applicaton, I have a `Datagridview` and `Textbox` control. I'm using a stored procedure to display some data in the datagridview. The problem is when I tried to search in my datagridview, nothing happens and also it's so laggy when inputting to textbox and I discover this

```
CustomersList.DataSource = dt;
```

is the reason. I'm pretty new to using stored procedures. I hope someone would be able to help me.

Here's the code for searching

```
Datatable dt;
private void txt_usersearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SalesInventoryManagement.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetCustomers", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                   
                dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Full_Name LIKE '%{txt_usersearch.Text}%'";
                CustomersList.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
}
```

and this code is to display my data to datagridview

```
public class Display 
{
    public static void Display_Customer(DataTable dt, DataGridView dgv)
    {     
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SalesInventoryManagement.Properties.Settings.Setting"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetCustomers", con))
            {               
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {                        
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    dgv.DataSource = dt;
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Form load

```
private void ManageCustomer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Display.Display_Customer(dt, CustomersList);
}
```

Comment: In the `TextChanged` event it appears unnecessary to re-fill the `DataTable` `dt`… Forget about refilling `dt` and simply create a new `DataView` from the existing `dt`  `var dv = new DataView(dt);` and then set the last line as `CustomersList.DataSource = dv;` not `dt`

Comment: Setting `dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;` would be enough. Also for client-side search, you can set `dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "FullName LIKE '%{textBox1.Text}%'";` You don't need to reset the `DataSource`, it's enough to apply the filter on `DefaultView` of the `DataTable`.

Comment: @JohnG I tried your solution but it cannot find any of my columns

Comment: You should update/edit your question to reflect this _“I tried your solution”_ … it is pure speculation to guess what you “tried.”  As @Reza Aghaei correctly points out, there are numerous ways to achieve what you describe.

Comment: @JohnG Updated Already, but when i type something the displayed data disappeared

Comment: You should remove ALL the code re-filling `dt` it is unnecessary and you are creating a NEW `dt` every time the text changes. Meaning everytime the user presses a key... the code re-fills the dt... The last two lines of code is all you need.

Comment: @JohnG Yeah i do that, but now it cannot find my column name Full_Name see the updated code above

Comment: @RezaAghaei Here's the updated code. tried your's but doesn't go well. Thank you

Comment: `private void txt_usersearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"Full_Name LIKE '%{txt_usersearch.Text}%'";}`

Comment: Do not search in database again. Do not create another local dt variable, I assume you have a `dt` field at form level. Do not ignore the `$` before `$"Full_Name LIKE '%{txt_usersearch.Text}%'"`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei see the updated code above sir.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Text Change event. That is not a good approach . I used to live search on Dgv EdiitingControl Event. You should put live search on Dgv and Kindly show me Stored procedure you write

```
private void dgv_sales_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
        try
        {
            if (dgv_sales.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex==0)
            {
                TextBox prodname = e.Control as TextBox;
                if (prodname!=null)
                {
                    prodname.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                    prodname.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ClientListDropDown();
                    prodname.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                }
            }
            else if (dgv_sales.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex==7)
            {
                TextBox prodname = e.Control as TextBox;
                if (prodname != null)
                {
                    prodname.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                    prodname.AutoCompleteCustomSource = BatchNoDropDown();
                    prodname.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                TextBox prodname = e.Control as TextBox;
                if (prodname != null)
                {
                    prodname.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;

                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }
    }
```

Comment: this event is for making Dgv live search

Answer (score 0):

Solved it :)

```
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Full_Name like '%{0}%'", txt_usersearch.Text);
CustomersList.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
```